# Is there a way to change the Shipping option of an order(already placed order) from the Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, shipping-methods, fedex, usps

Is there a way to change the Shipping option of an order(already placed order) from the Backed, ie change the Fedex option from Standard Overnight to Home Delivery.

Comment: by default no. you need to create your own solution for that

Comment: unfortunately all order edit modules are paid one

Comment: Please Provide the Links of those modules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can edit the order. But for this you have to use the paid extension. 
Below is one of them, It provides you full command of Edit a Order.

http://magemart.com/all-magento/order-editor.html